# Joining table using PXSelectJoin using cast in BQL statement

Tags: acumatica

I have a requirement to write a BQL statement for below SQL query

```
 SELECT * FROM CSATTRIBUTEGROUP INNER JOIN INVENTORYITEM ON CSATTRIBUTEGROUP.ENTITYCLASSID=CAST(INVENTORYITEM.ITEMCLASSID AS NVARCHAR(10))
  LEFT JOIN CSANSWERS ON INVENTORYITEM.NOTEID=CSANSWERS.REFNOTEID WHERE INVENTORYCD='CPU'
```

The EntityClassID in CSAttribute & ItemClassID in inventory are different type. How to join the table using BQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would be tempted to create a custom view representing the INVENTORYITEM table with a cast of ITEMCLASSID.  However custom views are not recommended.  Instead try creating a PXProjection to represent the INVENTORYITEM table as usrINVENTORYITEM.  Then use a PXString to convert the Int? to a string.  Once exposed you can work out your BQL as shown below.

```
#region InventoryItem - projection
[PXProjection(typeof(Select<InventoryItem>), Persistent = false)]
public partial class usrInventoryItem : InventoryItem
{

    #region ItemClassIDStr
    [PXString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ItemClassIDStr", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual string ItemClassIDStr
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{ItemClassID}";
        }
        set
        {
            this.ItemClassIDStr = value;
        }
    }
    public abstract class itemClassIDStr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
#endregion
```

then the BQL statement:

```
// basic example of your join.
 public PXSelectJoin<CSAttributeGroup, LeftJoin<usrInventoryItem,
            On<usrInventoryItem.itemClassIDStr, Equal<CSAttributeGroup.entityClassID>>>> ExampleJoin;
```